# How to fix 'read access violation' exception when handling integers in different classes

Tags: c++

When trying to 'equip' the weapon and Armour objects they result in a read access violation and the output damage and input is all blanks. (Anything in parenthesis is an alternative output) The output should be

```
Attacker : Gary using Wooden Sword does 1 (or 2) damage. 
Defender : Mary(4 HP) is equipped with Iron Armour and receives 0 (or 1) damage
```

but output is

```
Attacker : Gary using Weapon does  damage.
Defender : Mary( HP) is equipped with Armour and recieves
```

This is the code:

```
class Weapon {
        public:

         std::string weapon_Name = "Weapon";
        
        int MIN_DAMAGE = 0;
        int MAX_DAMAGE = 1;
    
    };
        
        class Wooden : public Weapon {
        public:

            std::string weapon_Name = "Wooden Sword" ;
            
            int MIN_DAMAGE = 1;
            int MAX_DAMAGE = 2;
        
        };

        class Iron : public Weapon {
        public:

            std::string weapon_Name = "Iron Sword";

            int MIN_DAMAGE = 2;
            int MAX_DAMAGE = 4;

        };

    class Armour { 
    public:
    
        std::string armour_Name = "Armour";
    
        int DAM_REDUCTION = 0;
        int DAM_ABSORBTION = 0;

    };

        class Leather : public Armour {
        public:

            std::string armour_Name = "Leather Armour";

            int DAM_REDUCTION = 0;
            int DAM_ABSORBTION = 1;

        };

        class Chainmail : public Armour {
        public:

            std::string armour_Name = "Iron Armour";

            int DAM_REDUCTION = 1;
            int DAM_ABSORBTION = 2;
                
        };

    class Player {
    private:
        int hp;
        std::string name;

        Weapon *WEAPON_EQUIPPED;
        Armour *ARMOUR_EQUIPPED;

    public:

        Player(std::string pName, int startHP) {
        
            this->hp = startHP;
            this->name = pName;
        
        }

        void equipWeapon( Weapon &Weapon){ this->WEAPON_EQUIPPED = &Weapon; }

        void equipArmour( Armour &Armour){ this->ARMOUR_EQUIPPED = &Armour; }

        void getWeaponName() { std::cout << WEAPON_EQUIPPED->weapon_Name; }

        void getArmourName() { std::cout << ARMOUR_EQUIPPED->armour_Name; }
        
        void getPlayerName() { std::cout << name; }
        
        int getPlayerHP() { return hp; }
        
        int getOutDamage() {
            
            srand((int)time(0));
            int outDamage = ((rand() % this->WEAPON_EQUIPPED->MAX_DAMAGE) + this->WEAPON_EQUIPPED->MIN_DAMAGE);

            return outDamage;
        
        }

        int getInDamage() {
        
            int inDamage = getOutDamage();
        
            srand((int)time(0));

            int totalDamage = inDamage - (((rand() % this->ARMOUR_EQUIPPED->DAM_ABSORBTION) + this->ARMOUR_EQUIPPED->DAM_REDUCTION) % this->ARMOUR_EQUIPPED->DAM_ABSORBTION);
            
            return totalDamage;
        
        }

        int recieveDamage(int inDam) {

            //this->hp - inDam;
            int dam =   this->hp - inDam;

            return dam;
        
        }

        
    };

    void Attack(Player& attacker, Player& defender) {
    
        std::cout << "Attacker : ";
            attacker.getPlayerName();
        std::cout << " using ";
            attacker.getWeaponName();
        std::cout << " does ";
            attacker.getOutDamage();
        std::cout << " damage." << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Defender : ";
            defender.getPlayerName();
        std::cout << "(";
            defender.getPlayerHP();
        std::cout << " HP) is equipped with ";
            defender.getArmourName();
        std::cout << " and recieves ";
            defender.recieveDamage(defender.getInDamage());
        std::cout << " damage(";
            defender.getPlayerHP();
        std::cout << ")" << std::endl;
        

    }

    int main() {
    
        Player Gary("Gary", 4);
        Player Mary("Mary", 4);

        Wooden wood;
        Chainmail chain;

        Wooden* ptrWeap = &wood;
        Chainmail* ptrChain = &chain;

        Gary.equipWeapon(wood);
        Mary.equipArmour(chain);
    
        Attack(Gary, Mary);

        return 0;
    
    }
```

Sorry for long code I do need help in understanding how to fix this, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should call `srand` only once, and you can't "override" member variables like you seem to be trying to do. Use constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at call stack while the exception if being thrown you will see, that in `main` you call `Attack(Gary, Mary);`, where `Gary` is an attacker and `Mary` is a defender. It then calls `defender.recieveDamage(defender.getInDamage());`. Then `getInDamage()`, calls `getOutDamage()` again on object `Player` and the instance of that object is `Mary`, for whom you never actually set `WEAPON_EQUIPPED`. And since it is uninitialized, it is by default a `nullptr` (at least on Debug) and here is where your `access violation reading` comes from.

Comment: I simply redid it all with constructors, thnx m8